# How to sort a hashmap containing arrays

Tags: powershell

I got a logdata which contains dates and IPs. 
Now I want to know which IP is for which day. 
I used a hashmap to use a key<=>value pair.   
But unfortunately there are duplicates like:

```
Day1<=>IP1, Day1<=>IP2, Day1<=>IP3, Day2<=>IP1, Day3<=>IP2, Day3<=>IP1
```

I used to use arrays as key<=> value pair so that I can still use 
duplicates as hashentries. Can I group the output of the hashtable 
so that it displays smth like this:
 `date<=>IP1, IP2, IP3` 
 `date<=>IP1, IP2, IP3` ?

I was thinking about the `group-object` method.

/edit:

Sampe input could be:

```
26.12.2014 1.1.1.1
28.12.2014 2.2.2.2
29.12.2014 1.1.1.1
29.12.2014 2.2.2.2
30.12.2014 2.2.2.2
30.12.2014 3.3.3.3
30.12.2014 3.3.3.3
30.12.2014 3.3.3.3
30.12.2014 4.4.4.4
30.12.2014 1.1.1.1
30.12.2014 2.2.2.2
```

I'm trying to get all the access per day. All the entries are arrays
because you can't have multiple values for your keys. 
The desired output should be smth like this:

26.12.2014: 1 
28.12.2014: 1 
29.12.2014: 2 
30.12.2014: 7

The number displays the access per day.

/edit 2:

sample code is like this:

```
    $items = Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot\*file*"
foreach ($item in $items)
{
    $item_name = $item.Name
    $content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines("$PSScriptRoot\$item_name")

    $hash = @{}

    foreach($line in $content)
    {
        $hash.Add(@(((filter_date($line)).split(" ")[1])),     @(((filter_date($line)).split(" ")[0])))
    }
}
```

filter_date is a soubroutine which cuts off the IP and date per line.

Comment: I need some sample input to understand your question properly, not just a drawing/concept. Please provide sample input and wanted output. Are the input multiple textfiles? If so, include a few lines from one of them (without any sensitive data). What have you tried?

Comment: Is this a text-file, or are you recieving a string-array from an API etc.? Could you include the script you use today/previously used?

Comment: The source is a folder which contains a lot of logdatafiles. I got about 1000 textfiles in there which I read in in a loop, file per file, and cut specific strings off. This works very fast for me. The output are, of course, Strings, wihich I continue processing.

Comment: See updated answer. Maybe that is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you only want the number of entries per day in a list sorted by dates. If so, I would recommend creating a single hashtable for the whole script, with the date as the key and a simple `int`-counter as the value. If you don't need to keep the IPs, then storing them are a waste of time and resources. Try:

```
#Create hashtable to store date = access per day.
$hash = @{}

#Get files
$items = Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot\*file*"

foreach($item in $items) {

    #The FullName-property of a FileInfo-object (result from Get-ChildItem) contains full filepath.
    $content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($item.FullName)

    foreach($line in $content) {

        $data = filter_date($line).Split(" ")#Expecting 2 parts: [0] = Date, [1] = IP

        if($hash.ContainsKey($data[0])) {
            #Date previously registered, count = count + 1
            $hash[$data[0]] += 1
        } else {
            #First instance of date, count = 1
            $hash[$data[0]] = 1
        }
    }
}

#Loop through hash
$hash.GetEnumerator() |
#Sort by date
Sort-Object { [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Key, 'dd.MM.yyyy', $null) } |
#Format result
ForEach-Object { "$($_.Key): $($_.Value)" }

26.12.2014: 1
28.12.2014: 1
29.12.2014: 2
30.12.2014: 7
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I thought too complicated to get this solution for myself...

Answer (score 1):

Any help? (Edited for new requirements and sample data)

```
$data = 
(@'
26.12.2014 1.1.1.1
28.12.2014 2.2.2.2
29.12.2014 1.1.1.1
29.12.2014 2.2.2.2
30.12.2014 2.2.2.2
30.12.2014 3.3.3.3
30.12.2014 3.3.3.3
30.12.2014 3.3.3.3
30.12.2014 4.4.4.4
30.12.2014 1.1.1.1
30.12.2014 2.2.2.2
'@).split("`n") 

$ht = [ordered]@{}

$data | 
foreach {$ht[$_.split()[0]]++}

[PSCustomObject]$ht | format-list



26.12.2014 : 1
28.12.2014 : 1
29.12.2014 : 2
30.12.2014 : 7
```

Comment: Don't you need to split on the whitespace o every entry? Like .split(" ") ?

Comment: @mushroomer - that's the default for .split().  It's just being used to provide sample data.  I'm sure the actual log file looks much different, and the OP already some method for parsing out those two values.

Comment: He does split every line at whitespace.